# Simulated speaker dummy load for solid state

Tags: solid-state-devices, dummy-load

This is specific for 6 string electric guitar amplifiers. The convention appears to be use a resistor equal to the nominal DCR of the intended speaker load, usually 4 or 8 Ω.

What I have found out was, although speakers have both inductance and resistance, the effective resistance is frequency dependent. So why should connect an essentially non-inductive resistor of fixed value to do load testing? According to the chart below for the Jensen 8CR, for example, the impedance rises to 13.7 Ω @ 5 kHz.

However, the guitar program is usually a complex mixture of fundamentals and all kinds of harmonics, so I'm at a loss as to what kind of test signal to use for load testing, or even if simulating a speaker load could be justified. The question arose for me when investigating the various ways to limit power if inadvertently exceeded such as a boosted device placed in the FX loop, or at the input for that matter. A soft-clipping circuit can be used as a dumb limiter, but these could cause other problems, too.  Moreover, clipping, especially asymmetrical, of the power amp is be avoided.

Jensen states the inductance of the 8 Ω is 0.43 mH @ 1 kHz if that's any help.

I see that Neureochrome makes an elaborate load tester for headphone amps to check for stability [Here](https://neurochrome.com/products/headphone-dummy-load). Would a high power version be of any value to load testing?

[image]

Comment: The better you can approximate the actual speaker load, the more accurate your stability testing gets. You have the impedance curve, which makes it pretty easy to construct a matching test load.

Comment: You can measure the electrical frequency response of a real speaker.

Answer (score 2):

A basic model for simulating a speaker is just an RL circuit.

You can add as much components you need to make a model as accurate as you want for some specific speaker, but it basically boils down to the question if the RL is good enough model, and if it isn't, then how detailed model you really need.

Especially if your amplifier must work with all kinds of speakers, so a generic model might be enough.

And it depends also what you mean by speaker. Just one driver element, or actual speakers you can buy from stores with multiple drivers and crossover filters.

If a driver, then the impedance is also affected
by how it is loaded by the enclosure it is mounted.

Comment: +1 for RL. When I designed audio amplifiers for a living, a calibrated RL dummy load + AudioPrecesion interface ($$$) was the gold standard for amplifier testing. Cheapo manufacturers would only test with R which simplified the situation for the DUT in question.

Comment: @Justme: Thank you for that commentary. Guitar cabinets almost invariably consist of one, two, or four plain, more or less mid-range drivers, without any crossovers.  Complicating this is some are closer to an infinite baffle, a semi-sealed, or fully sealed enclosure. They are usually 8 Ohm total per cabinet, sometime paralleled to 4.  In any case, is the model you suggest a series RL ?  That's what I envision; fairly easy to construct several.

Comment: But doesn't RL completely ignore the large mechanical resonance in the low-mid range?

Comment: @tobalt: It appears by the jist of the comments, a fixed driver simulator is completely ignorant of all actual driver dynamics.  The interest is maximum wattage at a range of frequencies of which the watt level would be lower in that range.

Comment: Correction: the fully sealed cabinet is close to an infinite baffle, i.e., no cancellation resulting in loss of SPL.

Comment: What you hear from a speaker is only sparingly related to the exact voltage/current flowing in its coil.  The cabinet, orientation of the cabinet/speaker in the room, shape of the room, resonances/materials/walls/ceilings/floors/windows/curtains/doors etc. also impact what you hear.  Heck, where you STAND affects what you hear.  I don't know what your specific need is, but bear this in mind.  A model, no matter how precise, is just a model.  It may or may not be "actually useful" for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Atomique That is a good point, but this is not about what comes out of the speaker which is a thing itself, as this was about if the amplifier can handle the speaker as a complex electrical load without problems. And there are common methods how to design the amplifier so it can drive typical speakers stably and there are different test loads for testing stability. Some universities have courses on audio electronics that should cover these.